# not getting data in Jquery.GetJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

i have a working example which uses this url

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=jQuery16201154390876987067_1314382298849&tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1314382298856
```

which gives me this json result (this is the beginning of it:)

```
jQuery162031768042474373037_1314374838725({
        "title": "Recent Uploads tagged cat",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/cat/",
```

When i paste this in jslint, it says it is not valid json

now i have my own json service, which returns this:

```
{
    "one0": "file201101_01.jpg ",
    "one1": "file201101_02.jpg ",
    "one2": "file201101_03.jpg ",
    "one3": "file201101_04.jpg "
}
```

which is valid json according to jslint.

now the first (seems to be invalid) one is read by jquery.getJSON, but mine (which seems to be valid) isn't.

when i look in firebug, it 'says' that no content is returnd from my service, but the url shown is returning content when i copy-paste it in the browser.

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("http://jadieda.com/myservice.php",  
    {    year: "2011",
        id : "1"
    },
    function(data) 
    {    
        alert(data);

    });
```

the alert(data) doesn't go off, so my guess was that the calling of the service did not return valid json (because of this from the help:As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently)

Comment: You're not calling JSON with the flickr api call. You're calling a chunk of JavaScript that is encapsulating that JSON. Look for `nojsoncallback` on the page here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html though you're going to run into other issues there.

Comment: See here, there's a flickr example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JSONToJSONP.aspx

Comment: huh? i've got this example from the jquery site from the GetJson page. So i thought..... that this is a json call to a json result?

Comment: from this page i took the example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: can i not use my code with a json result?. Or should i use something else to retrieve json and parse it?

Comment: Huh, okay. Well, if it's enclosed in `jQuery16205244302319542068_1314382972573()`, it's not JSON. It's a chunk of JavaScript and jQuery is doing some magic for you to get around the same origin policy. See: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: no, my service result is plain json. I was wondering wether tje getJSON method is the right approach then to get and parse that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which is a way of getting cross domain AJAX.

I don't know why your service isn't returning data without seeing the PHP. But if the status code is 204, no content. Then chances are you are not `echo/print` any data;